# Copy all the fields of a case class when only the mixed in trait is known

Tags: scala, reflection, slick, traits

First of all, I saw a few similar questions in SO and other forums, but many were for older versions of Scala. I was hoping if there is any other way possible for my situation. Also, I posted the same question in [scala](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lEIcKyV89xE) and [slick](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lEIcKyV89xEhttps://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lEIcKyV89xE) google groups, but did not receive any suggestion yet. So was hoping if anyone here could give some suggestions.

I have the below traits/abstract classes in my application.

```
trait Persistable

abstract class BaseEntity extends Persistable {
  val id: Long
}

trait Auditable {
  val createdDate: java.sql.Timestamp
  val modifiedDate : java.sql.Timestamp
}
```

All the table which are auditable will have created and modified dates. 
One of my case classes looks like this.

```
case class UserAccount(
  id: Long, 
  name: String, 
  createdDate: java.sql.Timestamp, 
  modifiedDate: java.sql.Timestamp
) extends BaseEntity with Auditable
```

My application is a `spray` and `slick` based REST application.
I am parsing the json sent from the client side into the required case class.
Now, I want to set the createdDate and modifiedDate in the application, rather than just saving what the client sends. There are two reasons for that, as I do not want to have timezone difference issues and also don't want anyone to mess up the createdDate/modifiedDate intentionally as well.

I am following the repository pattern to handle all the database operation in a central location.

```
 trait Repository[TTable <: BaseTable[TEntity], TEntity <: Persistable[Long]] {

  def insert(row: TTable#TableElementType): TEntity = {
    db.withSession { implicit session =>
      if (row.isInstanceOf[Auditable]) {
        // set the modifiedDate and createdDate here
        (query returning query.map(obj => obj) += row).asInstanceOf[TEntity]
      } else {
        (query returning query.map(obj => obj) += row).asInstanceOf[TEntity]
      }
    }
  }

}
```

How can I copy the whole `row` and modify only `createdDate` and `modifiedDate`. I guess this can be achieved by using `reflection`, but I read suggestions to avoid the reflection. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality. It is not just this case, I have a few other situations where if the case class is mixed in with another trait, modify some other fields.

Comment: Great question. It is really unfortunate such a simple thing is beyond Scala's design.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have createdDate and modifiedDate as the last two members of your case class with type Option[java.sql.Timestamp]. As far as abstracting over the inserts goes, that should be possible but will require some major Scala skills, because you have to make sure the things have proper Slick shapes that allow insertion. Probably more feasible to replicate the insert method for every table. You can customize the slick code generator to do that for you, which still takes a bit of tinkering but should be easier.

Comment: The reason for abstraction in the repositories is that we have many different situations to handle, which everyone implementing the repository trait need not worry about.  For eg: If the case class is mixed with a trait called "NamedEntity", then before insert, we need to validate if a record with same name exists. I should not be inserted if duplicate name exists. This is just one of the scenarios. We have many such constraits. Can you pls give me some hints on the slick shape issue you are referring to. Also, how bad is using reflection to handle this case ?

Comment: I doubt you can handle this with reflection. In general it is advices against reflection because type-safety guarantees are off and it is less performant. Look at the signature of Slick's += in the Slick source code. You should find Shape there. But I rather recommend to look into Slick's code generation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I should try with Code generation.